# Eclipse does not find ANY class nor function in PHP

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am programming for PHP in Eclipse 2020-09 on Linux Mint, but whenever I try to use a `default` class or function, I get an error `class not found` or `undefined function`.

If I start the program from the shell by `php -f myprog.php`, it does work fine. So, it must have to do with my Eclipse configuration or my XDebug configuration. Unfortunately, I don't find how and where to compare the settings shell vs. Eclipse/XDebug.

Can anyone give me a hint what and where to check? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you have configured here: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.php.help/html/reference/preferences/php_executables/index.html

Comment: First of all, this dialog is under Window | Preferences | PHP | Installed PHPs.
In there, I have only "PHP 7.2.24 (CLI) (Workspace Default)".
Under Edit | PHP Executable, it is the same, but the field for the PHP ini file is empty (I thought, in that case the default would be used?).
Under Edit | Debugger, I have "XDebug" on Port 9000.

But this actually DOES work. I can debug my PHP code.
The "only" thing is that the IDE/XDebug does not seem to find the "libraries", neither ZipArchive nor simplexml... do I have to tell it somewhere to use these modules?